# Django can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: django, datetime, python-datetime, datetimeoffset

If the time has not exceeded three minutes, I want to proceed to the next actions

django models:

```
class ActivationCode(models.Model):
   blablabla
    activate_code_expiry = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py:

```
activation = ActivationCode.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
if activation.activate_code_expiry < (datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=3)):
   blablablabla
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your question? You are stating that django can't to something, but you don't describe the desired outcome or the issue you are facing.

Comment: This compare not working: 
if activation.activate_code_expiry < (datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=3)):

Error detail:
can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes